# Out of Stack Space - How to optimize VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code to retrieve a specific date in a (somewhat) large excel spreadsheet(2,000 entries).
I just realize that my code will not work and it will only get worse. Could you please advise me.

I give to my function:

- array() that contain my data from an excel spreadsheet
- FirstDate which is the date I am looking for, as dd mm yyyy
- DateSave() to save all the position where this date appears (multiple transaction on the same day)

The code will not be able to work with a database of 5,000 row as it will have to stack it if the date is at the end of the table. What could I do to fix this issue?

Thank you very much

```
Function looping(array() As Variant, FirstDate As Date, DateSave() As Long)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim PositionInArray As Long

    PositionInArray = 0
    
    For i = LBound(array, 1) To UBound(array, 1)
        
                If array(i, 1) = FirstDate Then

                    ReDim Preserve DateSave(PositionInArray)
                    DateSave(PositionInArray) = i
                    PositionInArray = PositionInArray + 1

                End If
            
                'If end of list and array not initialize ie. Not value in it
                If i = UBound(array, 1) And (Not DateSave) = -1 Then

                    Call looping(array(), FirstDate + 1, DateSave())

                ElseIf i = UBound(array, 1) Then

                    'Array has been initialized
                    Exit For

                End If

            Next i

End Function
```

Edit: Change data base to excel spreadsheet

Comment: Are you actually getting an error or is this all theoretical?

Comment: Avoid `ReDim Preserve` this comes with extremly high costs.

Comment: If this is actual data in a database, I suggest you write a SQL query to do it instead.

Comment: If this is not data in a database I recomment to use a real database like SQL for your data. Excel is no database!

Comment: Yes actually, it is not in a database, it is in excel, I am going to edit it.
Why Redim Preserve is bad? 
I had the error once.

Comment: @VI55 because it needs to rewrite the array everytime you call it. Think of it like creating a new array with the new size, copy each value to the new array, replace the old array with the new array. Very ineffective, and slows down a lot if used a lot of times.

Comment: Even if it's not data in a database, I would [recommend using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32478268/111794), as most performant and declarative (which for VBA admittedly isn't saying very much).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've renamed the function and parameters. The function returns the result rather than having a `ByRef` parameter. I've used a collection to store the row indexes.

```
Function GetDatePositions(ByRef database() As Variant, ByVal searchDate As Date) As Long()
    Const colDates As Long = 1 'the index of the column holding dates
    Dim i As Long
    Dim collRowIndexes As New Collection
    
    For i = LBound(database, 1) To UBound(database, 1)
        If database(i, colDates) = searchDate Then
            collRowIndexes.Add i
        End If
    Next i
    
    If collRowIndexes.Count = 0 Then
        GetDatePositions = GetDatePositions(database, searchDate + 1)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim res() As Long
    ReDim res(0 To collRowIndexes.Count - 1)
    Dim v As Variant
    
    i = 0
    For Each v In collRowIndexes
        res(i) = v
        i = i + 1
    Next v
    
    GetDatePositions = res
End Function
```

**EDIT**

There is no need to search each consecutive date. We just need to keep track of the next date that is bigger than the search date.

```
Function GetDatePositions(ByRef database() As Variant, ByVal searchDate As Date) As Long()
    Const colDates As Long = 1 'the index of the column holding dates
    Dim i As Long
    Dim collRowIndexes As New Collection
    Dim dateFound As Boolean
    Dim nextDate As Date
    Dim tempDate As Date
    
    dateFound = False
    For i = LBound(database, 1) To UBound(database, 1)
        tempDate = database(i, colDates)
        If tempDate = searchDate Then
            dateFound = True
            collRowIndexes.Add i
        Else
            If Not dateFound Then
                If searchDate < tempDate Then
                    If nextDate = 0 Then
                        nextDate = tempDate
                    ElseIf tempDate < nextDate Then
                        nextDate = tempDate
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    '
    If collRowIndexes.Count = 0 Then
        If nextDate = 0 Then
            Err.Raise 5, "GetDatePositions", "No date found"
        Else
            GetDatePositions = GetDatePositions(database, nextDate)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim res() As Long
    ReDim res(0 To collRowIndexes.Count - 1)
    Dim v As Variant
    
    i = 0
    For Each v In collRowIndexes
        res(i) = v
        i = i + 1
    Next v
    
    GetDatePositions = res
End Function
```

Obviously, an assumption that all dates are rounded is made. But if dates also contain time (hours, minutes, seconds) then `tempDate = database(i, colDates)` needs to be replaced with `tempDate = VBA.Int(database(i, colDates))`

Comment: You could remove the recursive step entirely and transform it into a `Do Until` loop.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, that would save the creation of a new stack frame each time the function is called. I just made a quick answer that would not confuse the OP too much

Comment: Hm, I think removing recursion would actually result in a less confusing solution, especially for a beginner. Also it would literally never run out of stack space.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the suggestion. A good improvement would be to keep track of the next date. There is no need to increment by +1. I will edit my response soon

Comment: That is some amazing code, thank you so much. I feel like a total beginner when reading this... 
I know it is going to sound stupid, but how do I access the value stored into res in the sub calling this function?

Comment: @VI55 You would do something like ```x = GetDatePositions(db, myDate)``` and you can then use ```x``` as you would have used ```DateSave```. Alternatively, you could return the Collection instead of transforming to an array of Long

Comment: @CristianBuse , and the last line : 
GetDatePositions = res
Return the whole array, then I can access the values like so ? `Lbound(res,1)`

Comment: @VI55 If you read the above reply, where I called it ```x``` then yes, you could do ```LBound(x,1)``` if you need to. Anyway, I am just editing the answer with a bigger improvement. Just refresh the page in a couple of seconds

Comment: @Tomalak The LBound and UBound work with the index of the dimension. In our case we are looking at a 2D array and hence 1 stands for rows and 2 for columns. We use 1 here

Comment: @Tomalak I laughed so hard at this. Didn't know the expression. I had one yesterday :)

Comment: It happens. I don't have MS Office handy atm so I had no way of testing.